# How to install Goldendict on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, software-installation, rpm

I've tried to install **goldendict** on my **laptop** which runs **CentOS 7** on different ways:

1- I've tried to convert **.deb** package to **.rpm** with **alien**

2- I've tried to build from source (with error or **qt4** and **qmake** needed), I've managed to download **qt5** from it's site and install it, but still the problem remains.

3- I've tried to found a proper repository to install from it with `yum install` but not succeed

Can anyone please suggest a proper and stepped instruction for my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'goldendict' package that is part of [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).  Enable EPEL by installing the 'epel-release' package, then 'goldendict' will be available to install through yum.